# Nest.Time issue in SearchRequest.Scroll property in F# with Nest

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, f#, nest

I am trying to create a Nest.SearchRequest with the **Scroll** property for the type <'T> in F# (4.3.0.0) using Elasticsearch.Net and Nest 5.0.1. This worked fine without the Scroll property and I could query and index elasticsearch from F# via the API.

The problem I am facing is the exception

```
'nestTest.Scroll' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Nest.Time'
```

when running

```
let searchRequest = new Nest.SearchRequest<'T>(Query = query_container, Scroll = new Nest.Time("1m"))
```

with a otherwise working query_containter. I tried different constructors for Nest.Time but always received the same exception.

In earlier Nest versions the following used to work

```
    let searchRequest = new Nest.SearchRequest<'T>(Query = query_container, Scroll = "1m")
```

Any help yould be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a more complete example? I just tried adding `Time` with NEST 5.0.1 and F# and didn't see any exceptions.